# Swift: how to cast Any to comparable?

Tags: swift

I want to write a function to compare two objects by their property names.

```
func compareTwoObj(obj1, obj2, propertyName) -> ComparisonResult {
    let value1 = getPropertyOfObj(obj1, propertyName)
    let value2 = getPropertyOfObj(obj2, propertyName)

    if let v1 = value1 as? Int, let v2 = value2 as? Int {
        return self.compareValues(v1: v1, v2: v2)
    }
    else if let v1 = value1 as? String, let v2 = value2 as? String {
        return self.compareValues(v1: v1, v2: v2)
    }
    else if let v1 = value1 as? Double, let v2 = value2 as? Double {
        return self.compareValues(v1: v1, v2: v2)
    }
    else if let v1 = value1 as? Float, let v2 = value2 as? Float {
        return self.compareValues(v1: v1, v2: v2)
    }
    else {
        return .orderedSame
    }
}

func compareValues<T: Comparable> (v1: T, v2: T) -> ComparisonResult {
    let obj1 = v1
    let obj2 = v2
    if obj1 > obj2 {
        return .orderedDescending
    }
    else if obj1 < obj2 {
       return .orderedAscending
    }
    else {
       return .orderedSame
    }
}
```

Because the type of property is unknown, I need to cast property to Int, String and so on.

I don't want to write specific type in cast because I need to change the code if I need a new Type. Is there a way to cast value in a generic way? Like

```
if let v1 = value1 as? T:comparable, let v2 = value2 as? T:comparable {
        return self.compareValues(v1: v1, v2: v2)
}
else {
    return .orderedSame

}
```

Comment: What does your compareValues function do?

Comment: Don't cast to Comparable, **constrain** to Comparable. And you should work with generics and native key paths.

Comment: You could also fix this problem by using strongly-typed KeyPaths, instead of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this, unless `compareTwoObj` is also generic, and makes you specify the exact type of the property that's expected to be found by the string name.

`Comparable` doesn't mean "an object of type `T` can be compared to anything". It means specifically that "an object of type `T` can be compared to other obejcts of type `T`". Without knowing that `value1` and `value2` are the same type, you can't satisfy the signature of `compareValues`, which requires `v1` and `v2` to have the same type `T`.

```
func compare<T>(
    obj1: T,
    to obj2: T,
    byPropertyNamed propertyName: String,
    ofType: T.Type
) -> ComparisonResult {
    guard
        let value1 = getPropertyOfObj(obj1, propertyName) as? T, 
        let value2 = getPropertyOfObj(obj2, propertyName) as? T
    else { fatalError("Type error!") }

    return compare(value1, value2)
}

func compare<T: Comparable>(_ obj1: T, _ obj2: T) -> ComparisonResult {
    if obj1 > obj2 {
        return .orderedDescending
    } else if obj1 < obj2 {
       return .orderedAscending
    } else {
       return .orderedSame
    }
}
```